# How to echo out php code that will execute?

Tags: php, html, web, echo

I am making a website and would want to do the following, but I have no idea how:
echo out HTML code with PHP code, so the PHP code executes. I read the file and echo it, but the PHP code is just a string of text and does not execute.

For example:

[a website file dude.php]

```
<html>
<?php
echo "dude";
?>
</html>
```

[another website file, that tries to echo out dude.php file, with the PHP code executed]

```
<?php
$pathToFile = 'dude.php';
$myFile = fopen($pathToFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($myFile, filesize($pathToFile));
echo $theData;
fclose($myFile);
?>
```

But all I get, is dude.php echoed out with the PHP code not executed.

I do not understand why, maybe there is something with the "echo" command...

I hope that this was clear enough for people to understand. I really don't know any other way to explain it.

Comment: The above syntax seems to be correct, have you installed PHP and Webserver to run your PHP application?

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) statement.

Comment: In fact, `include` is not a function, it is a statement.

Comment: it can be used as a function too `include('file')`. also can use `require` in the same manner

Comment: Thank you very very much :) I am very grateful to you, I have been searching for this over 4 days now... IT WORKS!!

Answer (score -1):

Evaluate string code wiht eval($somePhpCode).
[-Documentation-](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)
But maybe you want to use include as well.